# simple gllery with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

I'm trying to follow a simple example for an AngularJS gallery. I've attempted to follow this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKe25THBoF4 but get nothing but an empty page at `http://174.6.222.12/angular/` my html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="album.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Angular Album</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="AlbumCtrl">
  <div id="thumbWrapper">
    <ul id="thumbList">
      <li ng-repeat="image in images">
    <img src="{{image.thumbnail}}" alt="{{image.description}}">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

while `album.js` looks like this:

```
 function AlbumCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.images = {
     {image : 'img/location.png', thumbnail : 'img/location.png', description : 'location'}
     {image : 'img/map.png', thumbnail : 'img/map.png', description : 'map'}
     {image : 'img/info.png', thumbnail : 'img/info.png', description : 'info'}
     {image : 'img/calendar.png', thumbnail : 'img/calendar.png', description : 'calendar'}
 }
```

Why am I not seeing anythings? What am I missing? :o

**edit A**

Hoops, yes right but I switched the curly brackets at the end now for braces and it still doesn't work as expected, `firebug` is still complaining `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` at line 6 in album.js...
also changed `<img src="{{image.thumbnail}}" alt="{{image.description}}">` for `<img ng-src="{{image.thumbnail}}" alt="{{image.description}}">` ... but no luck, still... :(
In fact, `firebug` on my `localhost` says this:

```
Error: Argument 'AlbumCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
    at assertArg (https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:1014:17)
    at assertArgFn (https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:1026:3)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:4463:9
    at https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:4098:17
    at forEach (https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:128:20)
    at compositeLinkFn (https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:4077:11)
    at linkingFn (https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:3793:14)
    at linkingFn (https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:3796:12)
    at linkingFn (https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:3796:12)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:3705:24 angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:5355
(anonymous function) angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:5355
(anonymous function) angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:4550
Scope.$apply angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:7478
(anonymous function) angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:971
invoke angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:2726
bootstrap angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:969
angularInit angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:948
(anonymous function) angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:14050
trigger angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:1713
(anonymous function) angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:1938
forEach angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:121
eventHandler angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js:1937
```

so it's not happy at all...

**edit B**

Ah, got something now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the closing curly bracket for my function in `album.js`, fixed that and get the display I wanted.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ng-src="{{image.thumbnail}}"` instead of src directly.

Edit:

Your Controller need to have the fallowing code, as sugested by @dheerajmanju1:

```
function AlbumCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.images = [
    {image : 'img/location.png', thumbnail : 'img/location.png', description : 'location'}
    {image : 'img/map.png', thumbnail : 'img/map.png', description : 'map'}
    {image : 'img/info.png', thumbnail : 'img/info.png', description : 'info'}
    {image : 'img/calendar.png', thumbnail : 'img/calendar.png', description : 'calendar'}
  ];
}
```

Comment: hoops, yes but I still haven't gotten it working yet, please see **editA** above.

Answer (score 1):

Images seems to be an object, but in ng-repeat you need an array.

It should be

`$scope.images = [{image : 'img/location.png', thumbnail : 'img/location.png', description : 'location'}....];`